# Can wlan0 & wlan1 both be active at the same time or will they interfere with each other?

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, broadcom

I recently installed Lubuntu on an HP Pavilion which had previously been running Windows XP.  The internal Broadcom wireless card was experiencing some drop off issues & is under Lubuntu as well.  Stuck a new Ralink external wireless adapter into the the USB port & now the wireless is working very well.

Uninstalled the b43 firmware so the BCM4306 card won't work but it still shows up under the wireless device list as wlan0 along with the Ralink adapter which is wlan1.  Not very good with linux so not sure if there's a "device manager" or the like to disable the Broadcom card.  Will it hurt to leave both wlan0 & wlan1 active even tho wlan0 will never be used?

Or can someone help me disable the internal Broadcom card?  Found this command = "sudo ifconfig wlan0 down"  but I'm not really sure what I'm doing here.  Does this command only bring wlan0 down for the current session & will wlan0 then reappear after the next restart?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have both interfaces up, that doesn't mean that they're active. Actually they're active when they have an ip address, wich in your case, it doesn't seem to be happening.

If you really don't want to have both interfaces up, you can take one down with the command you gave:

> sudo ifconfig wlan0 down

If you want it up again, just do

> sudo ifconfig wlan0 up

I would suggest you don't mind with both cards being up, as you are currently using the wlan1.

Comment: Hi LnxSlck, I am only using wlan1, in fact in the network manager it shows no activity what-so-ever for wlan0.  Zero packets sent or received.  I will play with the modprobe command chili555 suggested & if no luck will leave it as is.  thanks

Comment: A switched on WiFi interface generate noise and sends probes all the time, even if you don't use it, so it is better to bring it down if you don't need it... It also consumes power.

Answer (score 1):

Does wlan0 disappear if you unload the driver?

```
sudo modprobe -r b43legacy
ifconfig
```

If so, blacklist the driver:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist b43legacy"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "blacklist ssb"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Comment: Hi chili555 & thanks, thought I was unloading the driver by uninstalling the b43 firmware?  Have a bit of experience with blacklisting & so this good.  I know if it is blacklisted then it will stay down.  Going to give that a shot.

Comment: Without the firmware, the pci.id calls the drivers b43 and ssb anyway so that you can read in dmesg that you are missing the firmware! We may also need to blacklist ssb.

Comment: Hi chili555, sorry took so long to respond. Researching modprobe & found some of your posts on this subject, anyway after "sudo modprobe -r b43" wlan0 is still there.  Syslog shows several lines of " b43legacy-phy0 warning: Unexpected value for chanstat (0x7C00)".  But more importantly & not associated with the Broadcom card the syslog is full of messages from wlan1 =  "ieee80211 phy1: rt2800usb_txdone: Warning - Got TX status for an empty queue 2, dropping".  I see a number of threads from various linux forums indicating a patch?  Probably not a good idea to post log messages here :(  thanks

Comment: Please paste the entire log here and give me the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7117502/  -   thanks for the assist. This is the entire log from boot up @ 18:49.  By the way according to speedtest.net I am getting over 20Mbps download & over 10 Mbps upload. Pretty happy with that :)

Comment: Hey, I almost have a 15 reputation!

Comment: Please see my edit. It is b43legacy!

Comment: Yes sir, that did it.  Thanks for all your help chili555,much appreciated :0)